# Selector for input type radio :checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have a selector here:

```
input[type=radio]:checked + label:before {  
     content: "\2022";  
     color: #913921;  
     font-size: 20px;  
     text-align: center;  
     line-height: 18px;  
}
```

And this is not working since IE8 below NOT supported the pseudo-class selectors in css i've tried http://selectivizr.com/ but got no luck:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--[if (gte IE 6)&(lte IE 8)]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/selectivizr.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            input[type=radio]:checked + label:before {  
                    content: "\2022";  
                    color: #913921;  
                    font-size: 20px;  
                    text-align: center;  
                    line-height: 18px;  
            }
        </style>
    <![endif]-->
```

I already put `<!doctype html>` like what the other said to make selectivizr work.

is there any possible solution for this like jQuery or is there something wrong in selectivizr?

I came up with this solution.

```
$("#radioDivWrapper input:radio[name=option_radioDivWrapper]").change(function()
{
   var id = $(this).attr("id");
   $('#radioDivWrapperlabel').removeClass('selectedR');
   $('#radioDivWrapperlabel[for='+id+']').addClass('selectedR');
});
```

just add a class to style the label of an input type radio.

Comment: You can't do this selection with jQuery and I'm not familiar with Selectivizr. Is there any chance you can just restructure the HTML (and/or CSS) so that you do not need to use a selector like this? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Also, are you sure Selectivizr supports `:before`? I don't see it mentioned on their website and I don't see a reference to it in the source code. Also, IE8 does support `:before` - is that the only browser you need support in? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before

Comment: what i want to accomplish is that to put style on the label of the checked input radio type

Comment: Can you tell us what you are trying to do, how your `html` looks like ?

Comment: By now I hope you could have got a solution. But otherwise, this is my approach : Try to put the label and the checkbox in a div and onselect of the checkbox, you can assign a style to that label. ( checkbox > getParent > child <lable> or some such.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the meta tag for IE yet?

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1">`